# Normal , reverse, alternate, alternate-reverse in Android Animation

Tags: android, html, css-animations, android-animation

The animation-direction CSS property sets whether an animation should play forward, backward, or alternate back and forth between playing the sequence forward and backward. Is it possible to write a code for Android Animation that meets normal, reverse, alternate, alternate-reverse values which are in CSS animation-direction ?

**HTML5**

```
/* Single animation */
animation-direction: normal;
animation-direction: reverse;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-direction: alternate-reverse;

/* Multiple animations */
animation-direction: normal, reverse;
animation-direction: alternate, reverse, normal;
```

**Android**

```
switch (arg1) {
    case "normal":
        //Code here
        break;
    case "reverse":
        //Code here
        break;
    case "alternate":
        //Code here
        break;
    case "alternate-reverse":
        //Code here
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement is used to set animation in the backward position. The second if statement is used to create an alternate direction by setting the first cycle normal and the second cycle reverse.

```
class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    private final TimeInterpolator delegate;

    public ReverseInterpolator(TimeInterpolator delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        return delegate.getInterpolation(1 - input);
    }
}

    if (isReverseDirection) { // set animation reverse
        ReverseInterpolator reverseInterpolator = new ReverseInterpolator(animator.getInterpolator());
        CommonUtils.cast(animator, ValueAnimator.class, false).setInterpolator(reverseInterpolator);
    }

    if (isRepeatModeReverse && repeatCount != 0) { // create alternate direction
        CommonUtils.cast(animator, ValueAnimator.class, false).setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    }
```